# Using Visual Studio query builder to filter data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012

Currently I have two tables created in MS SQL Server(`postings` table and `user` table) outputting to visual studio 2012 to a grid view and details view. I am trying to figure a way to ensure that when the details view is paged into a certain user (there is only two users) then the only the postings of made by that user in the past will show in the gridview.

The `postings` table has an `ID` (primary key) that is in two parts with the first part being a unique identifier of that poster with the second part being a unique identifier of that POST. For Poster1 has ID of 45678987654_98765456789, 45678987654_234565432123, 45678987654_999999999 etc and Poster 2 has the id 98765678987_987654866, 98765678987_2828288282, 98765678987_1111111111 all up about 700 entries.

In the User table there is a unique ID as well that is the same for that Poster eg. Poster1 has id 45678987654_98765456789 and Poster2 has 98765678987_987654866. I tried to filter in query builder in visual studio by =, Like% and CONTAINS because in theory if the first digits of the ID for both POST and USER were analysed and compared then the specifications could be achieved. As the current ID in the details view could be compared to all the gridview IDs and only those that are alike and share the first 15 or so digits would then be accepted onto the details view.

However all of the ways I tried to do this in query builder using `Post_Id = table_Id` or like/contains formats didn't work. If there is another way to do it that or if there is a slight modification to the current method then that would be great to hear about.

Comment: Hey ur question need better formatting. It look massy. And not understandable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment Dhwani. Apologies about that, I think my question is complicated because the situation itself is complicated :P Not really sure how I can make it better, which parts need further clarification?

Comment: At least if you can do, Just make question readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to change the postings table. Where you have concatenated two values to make the PK, split it out into two columns, the first containing the userId, and the second the unique id of the post that you've generated.

Having done that, set the PK to be the combination of the two, and tell the db that the userId in postings is an FK referencing the PK of User table.

Once this is done, the data will be in a format that VS can probably understand better, and the db design will certainly be improved.

EDIT

SQL Code to create the FK:

```
ALTER TABLE postings  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_postings_user] FOREIGN KEY([userId])
REFERENCES user ([userId])
GO

ALTER TABLE postings CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_postings_user]
GO
```

If there are values in postings.UserId which have no matching value in user.UserId then this will fail. To check, run something like:

select *
from postings p
left outer join user u on u.UserId = p.UserId
where u.UserId is null

This will give a list of posting rows where there is no matching user row - ones where your data conversion maybe had a problem? Or there was 'orphaned' data there already.

Comment: Having said that the postings table is 700 odd entries so manually seperating them may be not so ideal. Is there any way within sql server to get string entries etc in this manner and create the two entities from the one? possibly using left/right syntax but not sure.

Comment: In fact the original data is from excel files so backwards concetenation is supported there so will try that.

Comment: If the UserId is fixed length (24 characters in your data shown), then you can use select left(full_poster_key, 24) to get the user id part out, and then use a combination of Right() and Len to get the postid part.

Comment: The userids were sadly mostly different lengths, therefore a fair amount of elbow grease was required (as excel's backwards concatenation only worked half the time). Anyway, I know have seperate   columns although the DB wouldnt allow linking of the FKs as you described which is unfortunate considering it is elegant use of the data. Any ideas/thoughts for how to restrict the gridview entries to only those with the same id as those in the SqlDataSource of the detailsview?

Comment: No help on the Grid, I'm afraid: I don't use SqlDataSource. On the FK's, I'm surprised. This is standard functionality. What DB are you using?

Comment: no worries, am using MS SQL server 2012. Not sure why it didn't work, maybe something to do with data types or the data already loaded on.

Comment: It should definitely work. I'll add some SQL code to the answer.